# ItemGroup With Custom Metadata regarding files

Tags: msbuild

I’m trying to create a “Files” task item group with a metadata attribute called “TargetPath” populated with the relative path to a file.

Example:
For these paths:

> D:\Test\Blah.exe
>   D:\Test\Config\fun.config
>   D:\Test\en-US\my.resources.dll

The output should be:

> File Target = Blah.exe
>   File Target = Config\fun.config
>   File Target = en-US\my.resources.dll

Here is my best attempt... hopefully this makes my question clearer:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Files Include="d:\test\**\*" >
        <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
     </Files>
 </ItemGroup>

<Message Text="File Target = @(Files->'%(TargetPath)')"/>
```

I'd like "TargetPath" populated correctly... currently it appears to be null or empty.  Anyone know what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

Yes, I realize I can do this:

```
<Message Text="File Target = @(Files->'%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
```

However, I'm building up this ItemGroup to use the ResolveManifestFiles MSBuild task, which requires that I build up a TaskItem with the TargetPath metadata attribute to be able to customize that value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to assign dynamic metadata to an itemgroup before it's created. In your example there's no need to create custom metadata since this information is already part of the well-known metadata, so you can just do:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Files Include="d:\test\**\*" ></Files>
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="File Target = @(Files->'%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')"/>
```

Or:

```
<Message Text="File Target = %(Files.RecursiveDir)%(Files.Filename)%(Files.Extension)"/>
```

**EDIT:**

This example uses [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2y3e43x.aspx) task to dynamically update the itemgroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="d:\test\**\*" ></Files>
</ItemGroup>

<CreateItem
    Include="@(Files)"
    AdditionalMetadata="TargetPath=%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Files"/>
</CreateItem>
```

Comment: I see that, however I'm trying to use another task that relies on the TaskItems I pass to it to have this metadata attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Modern MSBuild doesn't require CreateTask (since .NET 3.5).

You can do it like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Files Include="d:\test\**\*" />
    <FilesWithMetadata Include="%(Files.Identity)" >
        <TargetPath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</TargetPath>
    </FilesWithMetadata>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am liking the ***CreateItem*** method to use like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
       <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <CreateItem Include="@(Reference)" Condition="'%(Reference.Private)' == 'True'" AdditionalMetadata="TargetPath=$([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName(%(Reference.HintPath)))">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="DLLFiles"/>
  </CreateItem>

  <Message Text="HintPaths:  &quot;@(DLLFiles->'$(OutputPath)%(TargetPath)')&quot;" Importance="high" />
```

I am using Transforms to just get only the file name.

***Output:***

> HintPaths: 
>   "bin\Release\log4net.dll;bin\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll;bin\Release\RabbitMQ.Client.dll;bin\Release\ReflectSoftware.Insight.dll"