# How do I select all read-only files with msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to write an MsBuild script to zip some files up. I need to select all of the read-only files recursively from a folder into an ItemGroup to add to the zip.

I'm using the community tasks Zip task, but am struggling with selecting files based on their attributes.

Is there anything around to do this out of the box, or do I need to write a custom task?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the job with a bit of dirty command line usage.

```
<Exec Command="dir .\RelPath\ToFolder\ToSearchIn /S /AR /B > readonlyfiles.temp.txt"/>
<ReadLinesFromFile File="readonlyfiles.temp.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="ReadOnlyFiles"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<Delete Files="readonlyfiles.temp.txt"/>
```

That gives absolute paths to the files.

To get relative paths, try something like this:

```
<Exec Command="dir .\RelPath\ToFolder\ToSearchIn /S /AR /B > readonlyfiles.temp.txt"/>
<FileUpdate Files="readonlyfiles.temp.txt"
            Multiline="True"
            Regex="^.*\\RelPath\\ToFolder\\ToSearchIn"
            ReplacementText="RelPath\ToFolder\ToSearchIn"
            />
<ReadLinesFromFile File="readonlyfiles.temp.txt">
    <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="ReadOnlyZipFiles"/>
</ReadLinesFromFile>
<Delete Files="readonlyfiles.temp.txt"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) (added to msbuild 4) to figure out if a file is read-only like so:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MyFiles Include="Testing\*.*" >
    <ReadOnly Condition='1 == $([MSBuild]::BitwiseAnd(1, $([System.IO.File]::GetAttributes("%(Identity)"))))'>True</ReadOnly>
  </MyFiles>
</ItemGroup> 

<Target Name="Run" Outputs="%(MyFiles.Identity)">
  <Message Text="%(MyFiles.Identity)" Condition="%(MyFiles.ReadOnly) != True"/>
  <Message Text="%(MyFiles.Identity) ReadOnly" Condition="%(MyFiles.ReadOnly) == True" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Just tried this, but I get the error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.File]::GetAttributes('')" cannot be evaluated. The path is not of a legal form. It seems that %(Identity) is expanding to an empty string. I'm using ToolsVersion="12.0".

Comment: Can you tell me how you are executing the msbuild file?  Is it from the command line?

Comment: I'm able to the script above just fine.  Maybe there's something different with how your executing it or how you've written the script.  It might be better to post a separate question with the msbuild script.

Comment: It looks like somebody already had the problem I'm getting and asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010655/itemgroup-with-custom-metadata-regarding-files

Comment: The question referenced will work with msbuild 4.0 but does not work before 4.0.  The same goes for my answer.  I suspect you are infact using an older version msbuild.

Comment: I'm on version 12.0.30723.0  I'll post in a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663522/why-does-identity-expand-to-an-empty-string

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the community build tasks [site](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)?

It has a zip task and an attribute change task - they should get you most of they way there.

Comment: Hi, yes, I should have said - I'm using their Zip task. As you say, the Attrib task will change attributes, but I don't want to change them, I just want to select files based on their attributes.