# Why is there a need for a separate item in my MSBuild file?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

There are many articles (like [this](http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/07/20/include-extra-files-in-webdeploy-package/) and [this](https://github.com/sayedihashimi/publish-samples/blob/master/include-and-exclude-files.md)) that show how to add files to be published, and they all say to add something like this to the publish profile (.pubxml):

```
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
  <ItemGroup>
    <_CustomFiles Include="..\Extra Files\**\*" />
    <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
      <DestinationRelativePath>Extra Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
    </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Why is there a need for the new `_CustomFiles` item? Why not simply `<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="..\Extra Files\**\*">`? I tried it, and for some reason this causes every file in the project to end up in the deployed `Extra Files` folder. Can someone explain me this behaviour please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are asking about *why* this is required, I will have to dive deep into what this code means to explain what you're seeing. `<Message />` is our friend!

### The meaning of `%`

Let's first look at what % means by using it in a `<Message>` task:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_CustomFiles Include="..\Extra Files\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>

<Message Text="File: %(_CustomFiles.Identity)" />
```

When you run this, you'll get the following output:

```
File: ..\Extra Files\file1.txt
File: ..\Extra Files\file2.txt
File: ..\Extra Files\file3.txt
...
File: ..\Extra Files\etc.txt
```

Basically, the `Message` task runs once for each item in the item group, because we used %.

### What's in the item group?

Let's take a peek at the item group before we even make any changes to it. When this task begins, `FilesForPackagingFromProject` already has all of the files in them, with various metadata properties, including `DestinationRelativePath`. Let's see it by adding just this to our task:

```
<Message Text="File: %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Identity) -> %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.DestinationRelativePath)" />
```

This outputs:

```
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\PrecompiledApp.config -> PrecompiledApp.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\Web.config -> Web.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\App_Themes\theme.css -> App_Themes\theme.css
...
```

It's important to realise that this item group is not empty to begin with. You are trying to *add* items to it.

### The working code

When you have sub-elements in an element that has %, they apply once to each iteration, so let's now look at the working code:

```
<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
  <DestinationRelativePath>Extra Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
</FilesForPackagingFromProject>

<Message Text="File: %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Identity) -> %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.DestinationRelativePath)" />
```

For each item in `_CustomFiles`, we include it into the `FilesForPackagingFromProject` item group and set the `DestinationRelativePath` metadata property to the *appropriate* `RecursiveDir`/`Filename` values - basically the ones that apply for the current element being looked at. Let's look at what this outputs:

```
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\PrecompiledApp.config -> PrecompiledApp.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\Web.config -> Web.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\App_Themes\theme.css -> App_Themes\theme.css
...
File: ..\Extra Files\file1.txt -> Extra Files\file1.txt
File: ..\Extra Files\file2.txt -> Extra Files\file2.txt
File: ..\Extra Files\file3.txt -> Extra Files\file3.txt
...
File: ..\Extra Files\etc.txt -> Extra Files\etc.txt
```

## Including just a single file

If you wanted to include just a single file, you can do so as follows:

```
<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="..\Extra Files\file1.txt">
  <DestinationRelativePath>Extra Files\file1.txt</DestinationRelativePath>
</FilesForPackagingFromProject>
```

This has no `%` to expand anywhere, so it does exactly what you would expect: it includes a single file into the output.

## The broken code

Now let's try to include a single file, but without hard-coding the path and instead using the % expression from the original code:

```
<FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="..\Extra Files\file1.txt">
  <DestinationRelativePath>Extra Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
</FilesForPackagingFromProject>

<Message Text="File: %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.Identity) -> %(FilesForPackagingFromProject.DestinationRelativePath)" />
```

There are `%` here so things get expanded, but because this doesn't have a `%` in the item group element, the expansion works differently and things get pear-shaped:

```
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\PrecompiledApp.config -> PrecompiledApp.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\Web.config -> Web.config
File: ..\obj\TempBuildDir\App_Themes\theme.css -> App_Themes\theme.css
...
File: ..\Extra Files\file1.txt -> Extra Files\PrecompiledApp.config
File: ..\Extra Files\file1.txt -> Extra Files\Web.config
File: ..\Extra Files\file1.txt -> Extra Files\theme.css
```

So instead of adding `file1.txt` to the item group once, it iterates over the entire collection and adds `file1.txt` once for each file already in it. `RecursiveDir` is not set in this context, while `Filename/Extension` are the original filename of each file in the group.

Hopefully you can see now that this will create a file for each file in your entire deployment, but in a flat tree, and notably, the contents will be that of `file1.txt` rather than the original file.

When you include a wildcard instead of just one file, the same thing happens for every file matched by the wildcard.

### How to fix this

Stick with the `%(_CustomFiles)` fix. Hopefully you will now see why it's necessary and how it does what it does. I do believe this is how you are supposed to do this: here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010655/33080) about it, with an answer that recommends this approach.